# Calculate Throughput for Cassandra from its metrics?

Tags: cassandra, metrics, influxdb, grafana

I am using Grafana+InfluxDB to monitor the Cassandra performance.

I am able to get all metrics from Cassandra and feed into InfluxDB and visualise in Grafana.

I am unable to calculate the write and read throughput.

How can I calculate the throughput using Timer or Histogram metrics?

Comment: Throughput in terms of? w/r per second? MB/s? IOPS?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes **OneMinuteRate, FiveMinuteRate, FifteenMinuteRate** of the object **org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Read,name=Latency** gives the read per second over the interval of one, five, fifteen minutes.

Similarly the object **org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Write,name=Latency** has the write per second.

The metrics can be accessed through JMX and any other metrics reporters attached to cassandra.

Comment: Client request latency is a latency between client and coordinator of Cassandra node and we have these metrics, but here question is , how to calculate the throughput based on latency or some another way?

Comment: @ashokhein count on latency metrics provides the requests/s throughput.